# Internal Blu-Ray drive not recognized

Tags: windows-7, blu-ray, eject

This only just started happening yesterday, but when I put a BD disk into the drive and tried to do anything with it (just right clicking on the BD drive in Windows explorer), Windows explorer would just crash.  Manually pushing the eject button also wouldn't do anything, even though I see the LED on the front is on.

Today, I don't even see the BD drive as recognized hardware in device manager at all.  What have I done? There's a disc in there. :(

Comment: If there's a disc in there, you can eject it manually using an opened-up paper clip delivered to the hole designed explicitly for this purpose, in the front of the tray (but don't stab the LED!).

Comment: That didn't work, but I did manage to pry open the tray with a flathead screwdriver.  So got my disk back!

Windows still doesn't see it, though.  I found the model number by the way - LITE-ON iHES212-08.  I'll try opening up the case and seeing if the power cables need messing with, but the LED is still on so I doubt it.  It might have just failed.  For no good reason. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Drive has malfunctioned and due to its ability to power itself.

As randolph suggested:

[image]

this is a picture of a cd rom drive pointing at the hole you want to put your paper clip in, make sure you push slowly, and the drive bay will popup instantly. Which is why this hole is here in the first place.

I used to use Lite-on Drives years ago before i noticed their failure rate is extremely high. So i'm not suprised you had yours fail.

If you've switched around power ports and the drive still doesn't work, its gone, and it's time to get a new one.